# PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored - Creating a Procedure getting compile errors

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, stored-functions

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to create a ranking procedure based on the following tables:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
create or replace procedure rank
(para_userid IN number, USERID IN number)
is
     rank number;
     v_userid number;
begin
     v_userid := &USERID;
     select v_userid, sum(decode(a.rank, 'SU', 25, 'EX', 9, 'VG', 5, 'G', 3, 'F',1) * b.tokens) / sum(b.tokens)
into rank
from a.GameID = b.GameID
where para_userid = v_userid;
return rank;
end;



declare 
x number;
begin
x:=rank(&USERID);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User Ranking is: '||x);
end;
/
```

Comment: try replacing `v_userid := &USERID;` by `v_userid := USERID;`. Also, `rank` is a reserved word, you might prefer to name it otherwise. Also, stored procedures dont `return` anything. You need to create a `FUNCTION` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_rank (USERID IN number) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS
     nRank number;
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(DECODE(a.rank, 'SU', 25, 'EX', 9, 'VG', 5, 'G', 3, 'F',1) * b.tokens) / SUM(b.tokens)
    INTO nRank
    FROM a JOIN b ON a.GameID = b.GameID
    WHERE 
        para_userid = USERID;
    RETURN nRank;
END f_rank;



DECLARE
    x number;
BEGIN
    x := f_rank(&USERID);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User Ranking is: '||x);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you! It compiled successfully, however I am getting an PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'F_RANK' when I try to exec the function. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you, it works now after declaring para_userid number and setting it to userid at the beginning

Comment: oh, glad you found out!